# Testing connectivity between Unix and Windows servers

Tags: windows, networking, linux-networking, unix, telnet

I am doing a failover activity between 2 data centers.

In 1 data center, 1 Oracle database on Linux is replicating data to 1 SQL Server database on Windows using a replication tool.

There is storage level replication for the Windows server, so during the failover activity, the entire VM will failover with the same name, except with a different IP address.

The source is sending a SYN to the (new) target, but there is no evidence that the data packet is reaching the target, and there is no SYN/ACK being sent back.

How can I troubleshoot connectivity to find out if the problem is with Network firewall, Unix server, or Windows server?

(all teams say that there's no issue from their side)

Should I log into both servers and run telnet with IP and port, or is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Run your capture in more locations.  You say a SYN is being sent, but a capture at the destination might show that it is not being received, or maybe it was and the syn+ack was sent, but that isn't getting back to the sender.  On tough problems you might need to be capturing on both endpoints for and each intermediate device you control to figure out what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

Check that service is running and listening on all IPs, or its new IP. Packet capture the application's port on both ends of the conversation. traceroute / tracepath  to identify paths. The usual.

Examine all routers and firewalls between the two until you narrow it down. Provide evidence you have done your homework from the host perspective and want to know what happened to this conversation. In return, expect evidence that routing and firewall tables have been checked for this specific flow.